# How to reliably track d3.drag events going outside of the svg?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm starting with d3 so I might be missing some things.

I'm using d3 inside a React component, with `const svgRef = useRef();` and  `<svg ref={svgRef}></svg>;` and all the stuff happening inside a `useEffect`. The variable `svg` is  `const svg = d3.select(svgRef.current)` + some attrs/styles.

My understanding is, `offsetX` and `offsetY` are basically the sensible values for mouse events, that track with the svg's coordinate system. For `svg.on("click", event => ...)` they're right there in the event. For `d3.drag.on("drag", event => ...)(svg)`, there's `x` and `y`. In my case `y` is `offsetY + svgRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().top`, and `x` is is offset from `offsetX` by a mysterious value not present in the rect object.

But fine, I can retrieve `offsetX` and `offsetY` from `event.sourceEvent` for drag. Now if the user drags outside of the svg, I want to treat that as dragging to the edge. For too high values of the coordinates, a clamp works fine. But if the dragging goes e.g. above the svg, instead of becoming negative, `offsetY` changes to some value in the middle of the svg. So I can't tell from the event if it's above or in the middle.

What would be the right way to get the coordinate values also consistent for dragging outside?